# Why does my methods have no output?

Tags: php, class

I am creating a GoogleMapApi class. Found some in the net but I thought they are not very good for me. So I decided to build my own.

Actually thats not my first class and I am used to it....

Here is what I got:

```
class GMAPI{

    private $apiKey;
    private $from;;

    public function GMAPI(){

        $this->apiKey = GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    public function setFrom($string){

        $this->from = $this->prepareString($string);
    }


    public function getDistance($type="meter"){

        echo $this->from; //output is empty
        echo $type;       //outputs: meter
    }
}
```

now I have a other php file with this content

```
$gmapi = new GMAPI();
$gmapi->setFrom('New York');
$gmapi->getDistance();

//output: meter
//expacted output: New Yorkmeter
```

i have also tried this

```
public function setFrom($string){
    echo $string;
    $this->from = $string;
}
```

But still no result. Not even with

```
public function setFrom($string="foobar"){
    echo $string;
    $this->from = $string;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?!?!?

EDIT: **Shorted my Post to have a better overview**

### Full Code

[class.Controller.php](https://gist.github.com/Dwza/7d700fb276611350cde6)

[class.GMAPI.php](https://gist.github.com/Dwza/d0a29384cdb0128eb741)

(according to some comments i changed some var's to not have reserved var's in use)

Comment: "Bosten" should be "Boston"; TBH, am not 100% sure if that is the issue or not, but it is mispelled.

Comment: thats just a typo, but not my problem. my problem is that if i echo $this->from or $this->to its allways empty. changed my typo ^^

Comment: Ok. I thought your code worked in conjunction with Google. If Google can't find "Bosten", then to me, would've been a contributing factor.

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with a DB by any chance? You do realize that `from` and `to` are SQL reserved words; just saying.

Comment: actually yes. i have a pdo class included before and i call all this in the constructor in a other class. but as i posted, the getDistance has output, the other ones dont.

Comment: you sure this is the url google maps wants to understand? right now, if I go on google map, it does not use `q=` form anymore

Comment: I executed your code in a sandbox at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and it worked for me - have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Not sure but your constructor seems to me a bit weird isn't a php constructor suppose to be `public function __construct(){}`?

Comment: its up to the programmer... you can use __construct or the class name as well. i prefer class name because it looks smoother to me.

Comment: If your SQL's columns are indeed called `from` and `to` and you haven't wrapped them in backticks `\`` in your query, then that could be a big issue. Reserved words => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - Use error reporting as well http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - it may help.

Comment: my sql calls are `$this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM  XY");` its `$this->pdo->..` because its in the other class to

Comment: @Dwza self-named constructors are treated as regular methods from 5.3.3 when using namespaces, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @DarkBee ok. ill have a look at this but this still has non to do with my problem ^^ because there are other methodes which works fine ^^ and error_reporting(E_ALL) doesnt give me anything... im confused ^^

Comment: can you please create gist with all stuff that will help to reproduce problem (gist.github.com)?

Comment: Because your example causes PARSE ERROR, so maybe you're just not attentive. Here   ```echo $this->from //output is empty``` (missed semicolon)

Comment: excuse me for some lil typos here in SOF. of course i have a ; set there. i updated my question with my files. see bottom. all relevant data is there now

Comment: ```$this->gmapi->setFromAddress   =   "New York";$this->gmapi->setToAddress     =   "Boston";```

should be

```$this->gmapi->setFromAddress("New York");$this->gmapi->setToAddress("Boston");```

Comment: that was it!!! omg... im so.... hahaha... coding the whole day and failed like... ahhh... thank you very much. may you make a post so ill can vote you up

Comment: so you just created new properties instead of calling setters, I'll create answer that you can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code creates new properties on the fly, so it just should be changed as an example below

```
$this->gmapi->setFromAddress   =   "New York";
$this->gmapi->setToAddress     =   "Boston";
```

this code calls setters

```
$this->gmapi->setFromAddress("New York");
$this->gmapi->setToAddress("Boston");
```

Happy coding!

Comment: i even did it right on stackoverflow.... but i had it wrong in my code... may i should make a pause :D thank you very much

Comment: yeap, sometimes it happens and sharing code with somebody might help.

Answer (score -1):

them methods `setFrom()` and `setTo()` don't return anything. they only set a variable. even echoing won't work because there is nothing to `echo`.

Comment: this should be a comment. It is implied that they are empty in the map, when it is desired that they contain the location

Comment: They shouldn't return anything, they're property setters.

Comment: i know. they shouldnt return some. they just setting my property but later if i call propertys they are empty

Comment: i wrote this before he changed the question ;) i know that they are setters. thats what i say. but he updated his question multiple times ...

Comment: so why downvoting when his questions was different 5 min ago?! the answer was simply correct regarding his original question

Comment: @MarcAntonDahmen NO, my question was the same all the time. And i did no changes to my question. NOW i did some changes, i shorted my code for better overview. But as i sayed before, i know there shouldnt be anything returned. And this wasnt my question. may you just read some wrong.